# Detecting scratches in car surface, may be data drift

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, image-preprocessing, yolo, image-segmentation

I am trying to detect scratches on the car surface using Yolo, I have training images like the one below, and I am getting good mAP (around 0.83) on the validation and test dataset. The training image size is around 1600x1200. However, my actual images in production are having dimensions of 4000x3000, this model is not able to predict the scratches in production images.
I have tried resizing it, but it is not working. Any suggestions would be really helpful. 
training images - [image]
[image]

Production image -

[image]